# python tkinter cannot implement lift method on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to lift and lower a canvas object in Python Tkinter. I tried `canvas.lower()` but it's resulting in an error prompting

```
_tkinter.TclError:wrong # args: should be ".!canvas lower tag0rld "belowThis?
```

my script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.ImageTk as itk
window=tk.Tk()
image1=itk.PhotoImage(file="image_1.png")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window)
a=canvas1.create_image(0,0,image=image1)
canvas1.place(x=100,y=100)
canvas1.lower()
image2 = itk.PhotoImage(file="image_2.png")
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(window)
b = canvas2.create_image(0,0,image=image2)
canvas2.place(x=100,y=130)
window.mainloop()
```

the images are just a black square and a white square, so they shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you trying to list/lower canvas objects (like rectangles/lines/...) inside the canvas? Or you might be trying to lift/lower the whole canvas?

Comment: Show us how you created the canvas and image please. My guess is that you can do: `image_id = <tkinter.Canvas object>.create_image(...)` then `canvas.lower(image_id)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I mean to lower the whole canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lowering the whole canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk

import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, bg="red")
canvas1.place(x=100,y=100)

canvas2 = tk.Canvas(window, bg="blue")
canvas2.place(x=100,y=130)

canvas2.tk.call('lower', canvas2._w, None)

window.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

This directly calls the `tcl` command but still works. The problem was that in the definition of `tkinter.Canvas`:

```
class Canvas(Widget, XView, YView):
    ...
    def tag_lower(self, *args):
        """Lower an item TAGORID given in ARGS
        (optional below another item)."""
        self.tk.call((self._w, 'lower') + args)
    lower = tag_lower
```

It overrides the `Misc` class's (the base class for all widgets) method `.lower` that lowers the widget. So I directly called what the `Misc` class would have called: `self.tk.call('lower', self._w, belowThis)`

Comment: @willywillycow I edited my answer. I think that is what you are looking for

Comment: Why dont you add `lift()`.

Comment: @willywillycow Use `place()` to put place the canvas instead of `pack()`.?

Comment: @willywillycow I edited my answer try that. I also added explanation for why that was happening

Comment: @willywillycow Basically the `Canvas` class overrides the `.lower` method that all other widgets have. To lower a canvas we need to directly call what `<tkinter.BaseWidget>.lower` would call. If you still don't get it, try reading about inheritance and polymorphism. When you said that it hides the canvas, is that because the widget that goes on top covers the canvas fully? If you still can't fix the problem please post a bit more code so that I can see what is going on.

Comment: @willywillycow I have no idea where to file a bug report/comment to but it is a good idea. Also if this was the answer you were looking for please consider accepting it so that other people don't waste time coming up with the same solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain what is self._w?

Comment: @willywillycow It is the unique name that tkinter gives the widget. Tkinter is a wrapper for tcl which names all of the widgets. Tkinter stores the name of the widget in `self._w`